# How to represent a line of $\mathbb {R}^3$ in a different coordinate system?

Tags: geometry, coordinate-systems

I came along this question while trying to simplify the solving of intersection point of lines and surfaces. I am not sure if this will help my initial problem but I am now interested if there is a solution to this. I briefly read about this transformation in a physics paper, but can't figure out how it might be done.

In $\mathbb {R}^3$ there is a line, for example

$L=\left(
\begin{array}{c}
1\\
1\\
2
\end{array}
\right) +v\, \left(
\begin{array}{c}
1/\sqrt{6}\\
1/\sqrt{6}\\
2/\sqrt{6}
\end{array}
\right)$

and a "moving" coordinate system along some curve $c(s)$
$X(s)=\left(
\begin{array}{c}
\cos(s)\\
0\\
-\sin(s)
\end{array}
\right)$, $Y(s)=\left(
\begin{array}{c}
0\\
1\\
0
\end{array}
\right)$, $Z(s)=\left(
\begin{array}{c}
\sin(s)\\
0\\
\cos(s)
\end{array}
\right)$

I know the line will be a curve in this coordinate system, but I don't know how to calculate the equation. If there was a Cartesian representation of the line, the transformation would be obvious. But the Cartesian representation of a line consists of two equations or the formula

$\frac{x-1}{1/\sqrt{6}}=\frac{y-1}{1/\sqrt{6}}=\frac{z-2}{2/\sqrt{6}}$

how can one obtain from this one equation for the line in the other coordinate system?

Comment: Use the matrices of transformation depending of the coordinate system.

Comment: @skpblack To transform the point and vector of the line? But then I'll have a line in the parameters $s$ and $t$, but the resulting curve should just be depending on one parameter?

Comment: What is $c(s)$?

Comment: @FaraadArmwood A curve (here helix) from which I derived the coordinate system. (I did not use the frenet frame on purpose but found a vector Y(s) which is never parallel to the tangent and constructed an orthonormal basis).

Comment: Got it. I see $X(s), Y(s), Z(s)$ is the frame.

Comment: I hope what I wrote below helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have an orthonormal basis in the frame $\{X(s), Y(s), Z(s) \}$ i.e all are perpendicular and unit length. Hence, if we let $L(v) = p + tv$ as you've defined then at $L(v)$ we have the vector $v$ and so,

$$ v= (X(s)  \cdot v) X(s) + (Y(s) \cdot v) Y(s) + (Z(s) \cdot v) Z(s)$$

which gives the representation of your line in this moving frame. How I got to the above is just by observing that,

$$ v = a X(s) + b Y(s) + c Z(s)$$

and now take dot products with $X(s), Y(s), Z(s)$ using the fact that they are pairwise orthogonal and unit length to recover $a,b,$ and $c$. Just a fun fact, whenever you have such a basis, we call the above expansion, an orthonormal expansion (see *"Elementary Differential Geometry"* by **B. O'Neill**).

Comment: Thank you, that is exactly what I have been looking for! That reminds me of quantum mechanics, what happens if a system changes its state. But I've never came across this in mathematics or knew the formal foundation of it.